# Cannot Identify Zombie Object in iPhone Application

Tags: iphone, uitableview, exc-bad-access, nszombie

I am a noob making a simple signature capture application for the iPhone.

The application is suppost let the user navigate to a table view populated with deliveries. Then, they would click on the delivery they are currently delivering.

I am coming across an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error when I try to load the table view, so I ran the Zombie Diagnostic Instrument to see if i could find the problem. I got a Zombie error, however non of the "Responsible Caller"'s are in reference to any code I wrote.

So the basic flow of my app thus far is I have a View that has 3 buttons on it, one of them leads to a table view and then it crashes if you use it.

this is the code for the view switch:

```
-(IBAction) deliveriesButtonClicked:(id)sender {
    if (self.deliveriesViewer == nil) {
        DeliveriesViewerController *aOptionController = [[DeliveriesViewerController alloc] initWithNibName: @"DeliveriesViewerController" bundle: nil];
        self.deliveriesViewer = aOptionController;
        [aOptionController release];
    }

    [self.mainNavigationController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self.view insertSubview:self.deliveriesViewer.view atIndex:0];

}
```

This is the code for the deliveries class that it is switching to

**Header:**

```
#import < UIKit/UIKit.h >

@interface DeliveriesViewerController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate> {
    IBOutlet UITableView *myTable;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UITableView *myTable;

@end
```

**Implementation:**

```
#import "DeliveriesViewerController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation DeliveriesViewerController

@synthesize myTable;

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}    

- (void)viewDidUnload {

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    return appDelegate.invoices.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    cell.text = [appDelegate.invoices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

@end
```

If anyone could possibly help me find this problem it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is deliveriesViewer set as a retain property?

Comment: Yes it is set to retain.

Comment: post the code where you create the invoices array

Comment: 'NSMutableArray *newInvoices = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    
    [newInvoices addObject:@"06271991"];
    [newInvoices addObject:@"Test number 2"];
    
    self.invoices = newInvoices;
    
    [newInvoices release];'

invoices is retained

Comment: You're missing a `[super viewDidUnload];` in your `-viewDidUnload` method. Also can you post a screenshot/transcript of the output of your NSZombie detection?

Comment: ok i added the super call and here is the link to a screen shot [link](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B3olhtdgJW_dNWM4MmNjNDMtNjdmMC00ZWM4LWIzZDktN2U0NDU5MmI0N2Qy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem.

The problem was that i had the wrong datasource and delegates for the table view.
By default was set to the tableview itself not to the file owner.

Thank you for showing intrest in my problem.

Comment: what's happen with me is something similar.. the instrument doesn't show the responsible caller. at the same time the show the issue '[NSObject respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance' after I enabled tracking NSZombie in Xcode. the issue was two object was having the responsibility of alloc & dealloc the object one from the super class and the other one from nib file ." I hope my comment is useful enough to help people"